# Why did the os.read return empty in second call in python

Tags: python

I try this

```
fd = os.open("myfd.txt",os.O_RDWR)


In [28]: os.read(fd,24)
Out[28]: 'my test is good\n'

In [29]: os.read(fd,24)
Out[29]: ''
```

why did it return empty during second call

also when print `fd` it returns `3` as filedescriptor , what is meant by number 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at that point, the file pointer is positioned at the end of the file (due to the first read pulling out all the data).  It looks like you need an `os.lseek` to reset the file pointer:

```
print os.read(fd,24)
os.lseek(fd,0,0)
print os.read(fd,24)
```

Note that normal file objects are typically much easier to work with if you can help it:

```
with open('filename') as fin:
    print fin.read(24)
    fin.seek(0)
    print fin.read(24)
```

Comment: then why we need `fd` for , any special case for that where normal open can't do the job and `fd` can

Answer (score 0):

When you made that first read call, the file pointer moved 24 bytes (or characters) ahead, so you probably hit the end of the file.

And 3 is just a descriptor, it doesn't have any meaning to anything else than the operating system. The reason it's 3 is because descriptors 0, 1, and 2 are already taken by default (0 = stdin, 1 = stdout, 2 = stderr)